# How to set items on left and right with grid column in windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Can anyone say how to do like that:

In a pop-up I have two items one textblock and one image, in function of size of text I need to put all times text on left and icon right, like in the second picture.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="TEXT"/>
         <Image Grid.Column="1" />
 </Grid>
```

First Image is like that when first column is set auto: [image]

When set an static width:

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="TEXT"/>
             <Image Grid.Column="1" />
     </Grid>
```

After set

[image]

I want to set dynamic, not with a static value in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `HorizontalAlignment` of the element in the grid:

```
<Grid HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="TEXT"/>
         <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

This should put the image on the right hand side of the column. You might find you have to tell the grid to stretch to fill it's container as well.

Alternatively, assuming that your icons are the same sizes, you could swap the column definitions:

```
<Grid HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="TEXT"/>
         <Image Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

so that the second column takes it width from its content (the icons) and the first stretches to fill the available space.

With this sort of problem you often have to try two or three things to get the exact behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe he's looking to set them to percentages of the entire space?  Like 3*, 2*, or 3/5ths of the total width for the tb and 2/5ths of the total for the image?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="TEXT" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
         <Image Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
 </Grid>
```

You might also need to set the vertical alignment for both TextBlock and Image if this is the only content on the page. As then the content might come in the center of the page.

Comment: hi, elements shown are in left and right position, but i want to have some distance auto between text and image like in the second picture, it's possible something like that or I Wrong?

Comment: For that you can just set some margin to Image.Something like Margin="20,0,0,0" . This should give some space between text and image even when your first column is set to auto.

Comment: yes works that, but I don't want to put a static value, if you watch in the second picture I set width to text block to 400, when you say to put margin to image sounds like when I put width to text block